# javascript inner function variable access from outside

Tags: javascript, jaggery-js

Here is my code.
I need to access inner function variable in outer function

```
var json = {}, state, response;
readRequestValues();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if(xhr.readyState == 4){
    json.state = xhr.readyState;
    json.response = xhr.responseText;
    log.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+json.state+">>>>>"+json.response);
    var retValue=JSON.stringify(json);
    log.info(">>> THIS IS RESULT >>>"+retValue);

 }
}
xhr.open("GET", strBackend, true);//async=true
xhr.send();

log.info(">>> HERE I NEED TO ACCESS retValue >>>"+retValue);
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't. It not received yet here.

Comment: declare it outside and assign inside, but if its any callback then you can't.

Comment: why you want to do this. write your code in callback itself

Comment: it's scope is inside onreadystatechange only if you want the value you can declare it outside and assign it after request complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It not received yet here.
You should call any code, when we get it:

```
var json = {}, state, response;
readRequestValues();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if(xhr.readyState == 4){
    json.state = xhr.readyState;
    json.response = xhr.responseText;
    log.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+json.state+">>>>>"+json.response);
    var retValue=JSON.stringify(json);
    log.info(">>> THIS IS RESULT >>>"+retValue);

    logValue(retValue); // here we call logger

 }
}
xhr.open("GET", strBackend, true);//async=true
xhr.send();


function logValue(val) {
  log.info(">>> HERE I NEED TO ACCESS retValue >>>"+val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about inner and outer functions as much as synchronous and asynchronous functions. `onreadystatechange` callbacks are asynchronous, so you have to call the function that uses the received data inside the callback. Otherwise you anyway don't have access to it.

The last line in your code (`log.info(...)`) will always execute before the data is received inside the callback.